# CodeIgniter REST_Controller POST method returning GET

Tags: rest, api, codeigniter, post, get

I'm using [REST_Controller](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) CodeIgniter library in my project.

I have a login post method that cannot being reachable because REST_Controller is setting method as **GET** even if I do a **POST**.

Here is a snippet of my *Auth.php* controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . '/core/REST_Controller.php';

class Auth extends REST_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login_get()
    {
        echo('get');
    }

    public function login_post()
    {
        echo('post');
    }
}
```

When I do a **POST** at http://localhost/auth/login using [RESTED](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rested/eelcnbccaccipfolokglfhhmapdchbfg) Google Chrome extension I'm getting the `echo('get')`.

Debbuging **REST_Controller** I could see that the function `_detect_method()` is returning method as **GET**, and this is because in the function `method()` of *Input* core class of CodeIgniter `$this->server('REQUEST_METHOD')` is returning **GET**.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I got the solution!

This was happening just because I forgot to enable **mod_rewrite** in my Apache.

This fixes the problem:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: strange!! it should show you 404 error. since your mod_rewrite was disabled and your URL didn't have `index.php` like,`http://localhost/index.php/auth/login`

Comment: @jagad89, true. I don't know why I didn't have 404. If I got, it would be easier to get to know that it was a mod_rewrite problem.